# Correctly detect mixed-endian floating point format on ARM platform

Tags: c++, c, arm

I recently ran into an issue with a third party library that was using the following code to test for mixed-endian floating-point format on ARM platforms:

```
#if defined(__arm__) && !(__ARM_EABI__)
```

This check was incorrectly detecting mixed-endian format on Android platforms but worked correctly on iOS platforms. After some research I found the [debian ArmEabiPort document](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmEabiPort) which contains the following in the *GCC preprocessor macros for floating point* section which says(*emphasis mine*):

> When porting code to "armel", the following preprocessor macros are
>   interesting:
>
> - __VFP_FP__ means that the floating point format in use is that of the ARM VFP unit, which is native-endian IEEE-754.
> - __MAVERICK__ means that the floating point format is that of the Cirrus Logic MaverickCrunch, which is also IEEE-754 and is always little-endian.
> - __SOFTFP__ means that instead of floating point instructions, library calls are being generated for floating point math operations so that the code will run on a processor without an FPU.
>
> __VFP_FP__ and __MAVERICK__ are mutually exclusive. **If neither is set, that means the floating point format in use is the old mixed-endian** 45670123 format of the FPA unit.

For our specific case updating the check to the following fixed the problem:

```
#if defined(__arm__) && !(__VFP_FP__)
```

and works on both Android and iOS platforms. Although from the document the more correct check would be:

```
#if defined(__arm__) && !(__VFP_FP__) && !(__MAVERICK__)
```

We would like to submit a patch back to the third-party but considering the old check did work for the person who submitted it and how difficult it is to find documentation I don't feel like I have enough information to get this correct.

Are there cases the last check misses? The debian document specifically covers `gcc`, how portable are these macros?

**Update**

Based on the helpful comments from artless noise the question boils down to:

The `__ARM_EABI__` macro check was introduced as a patch by another user to check for mixed-endian floating point format. So apparently there are systems that this macro works for, what systems are those? Would the `__VFP_FP__` macro cover those systems or do I need to  take that macro into account as well to prevent breaking existing users when I submit a patch.

Comment: @artlessnoise tagged `gcc` because that is what we are currently building with but I should probably remove that tag since it is a little confusing. Since we want to submit a patch back to the open source project the code should ideally be more portable but we don't have the ability to verify and I doubt the project does either.

Comment: @artlessnoise as for the VFP quote, the rest of it says *It only speaks of the floating point data format in use* which is what we care about, I edited the post to mention we are care about floating point format.

Comment: @artlessnoise personally using `gcc 4.8` and higher and `clang 3.4` and higher. The platforms are relatively recent Android and iOS devices. A truly portable check may be difficult based on your initial comment, it would be nice to at least understand the limits a little better. Are there platforms that the original check would work for but the new one I am using would not work for?

Comment: For that use case, I think that [*Cirrus Logic EP93xx ARM*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MaverickCrunch) is probably not worth worrying about; It sounds like modern cell phone OS's.  I think the intent of *__ARM_EABI__* was to detect passing information?  It seems [ARM_PCS](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2140) is a better method for gcc4.6+.  Is it to swap passed parameters or pointer data?  It seems that *VFP_FP* may depend on the CPU type selected.  On a Cortex-A5, I get *VFP_FP* all the time with gcc, but on an ARM926 (very old ARM type) it is not on.

Comment: @artlessnoise thank you, your comments have been helpful. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

You'll also want to check to make sure you aren't on a soft-float toolchain, as the soft-float libraries don't have the mixed-endian issue:

```
#if defined(arm) && !defined(__SOFTFP__) && !defined(__VFP_FP__) && !defined(__MAVERICK__)
```

As to compiler support -- these should work in clang, but obviously, the commercial ARM compilers will do something else entirely.