# For testing purposes: which floating point (IEEE754 32b) numbers are "special"?

Tags: c++, c, testing, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm planning to test a cross-platform [SIMD library](https://libvolk.org) in more detail.

As part of that, I'd like to make sure I test a lot of the corner cases of floating point numbers for consistent behavior.

I can only come up with a few, like

- zero and negative zero,
- the positive and negative infinites,
- multiple versions of NaN,
- denormalized numbers

Now, especially the last two points give me headaches: I'm not even sure I understand the binary representation of what makes a (32b) float a NaN, much less the distinction between the different types (it seems there's three of these, quiet, signalling and "plain" NaN, but I'm really not sure they've got their own representation).

Also, denormalized numbers are exponent-all-zero, mantissa non-zero.

Is there a way of programmatically generating all these special numbers (Ok, +zero is easy, just interpret a 32bit 0-int to float)? I'm working on a C(99) and C++(11) library, so either one would be fine.

Comment: So, are you using c/c++ `float` or some custom type? If so, then look at [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), it contains all bit patterns and what they mean. If you are testing the library against some gold standard implementation, then you may simply test all the numbers, 2^32 is not impossible to test. Go through all `uint32_t` and memcpy them into a `float`.

Comment: it's all plain C/C++ floats. Point is that I looked at the spec and learned that I'd really want some well-tested way to generate the special numbers. Also, I'm just realizing that there's numbers (aside from 0) that have ambiguous representation; my problem is not how to craft a IEEE754 float in memory, my problem is knowing which ones to craft.

Comment: There are quiet NaNs and signalling NaNs, no "plain NaNs".

Comment: @Quimby I haven't found in IEEE754 whether endianness is defined; is it?

Comment: Denormal floats are evil. Just don't use them and tell the user of your API to never use them. Also read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @rustyx sorry, can't choose what the users of a library use it for. Even if I document they shouldn't be used, still need to test them for numerical reasons, in some cases.

Comment: I'm not sure what your needs are for your use cases.  Assuming IEEE 754 (ISO 60559), `0.0` and `-0.0` are numerically equal (with a few cases where they differ in results).  And `quiet NaN` and `signaling NaN` represent the same condition, but with different side effects.  Denormalized number can greatly adversely impact performance.

Comment: @Eljay exactly my problem. I'm doing testing of a medium-to-large set of algorithms across a set of different unoptimized and SIMD-optimized implementations for different platforms. So, performance *is* critical, but for testing, it's critical that e.g. the "generic C" impl gives the same result as the NEON impl as the SSE2 impl as the AVX2 implementation of "(float32,float32)-complex to magnitude squared".

Comment: Hence, my need for a way of quickly testing these notorious corner cases, before trying to cover the overall float range with sensible random subsampling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which floating point (IEEE754 32b) numbers are "special"?
>
> - zero and negative zero,
> - the positive and negative infinites,
> - multiple versions of NaN,
> - denormalized numbers

That's pretty much it, though there is no "plain" nan. Other numbers that may be important for testing: value ranges where all continuous integers are not accurately representable. Pairs of values that would result in special values. Minimum (normal) and maximum positive representable values.

> Is there a way of programmatically generating all these special numbers

Some are easy to generate with `std::numeric_limits`. It has member functions for quiet nan, signaling nan, infinity, smallest normal and denormal.

Others (such as nan with arbitrary payload) can be generated by using uint32_t, with bit mask that matches the IEEE specification, that can be `memcpy`ed over the floating point. Note that there may be obscure systems where endianness of integer and floating point differ, in which case the bitmask won't be what one would expect.

Comment: Ah, interesting, but I assume that ARM, PPC, x86, x86-64, and possibly MIPS and RISC-V won't be in the category of "obscure systems", right?

Comment: @MarcusM&#252;ller I&#39;m not intimately familiar with the hardware, but it may be a an issue on ARM https://stackoverflow.com/q/26105686/2079303 (so, possibly not quite so obscure)

Comment: ooooh a rabbit hole!

Comment: @Marcus Müller, I don't know about the others you listed, but both x86 and x86-64 have the same endianness (little) for both floats and ints.

Comment: @Marcus Müller, In any case, it's easy to detect the byte order and adjust to compensate in addition to copying them if required.

Comment: @ikegami point is that I was asking for a way of getting this down right without having all to do the bit twiddling manually, hence my question about an easy way of programmatically producing these special-case numbers.